# Node.js express - body of POST request is always empty

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, post

I am trying to read the body of POST request using Express in Node.JS framework. I send a HTTP POST request using HTML form. I detected a POST request on WireShark with the following data:

[image]

This shows that the request is sent successfully. I expected JSON format, which is the one that Express successfully parsed for me, but this format just doesn't seem to work no matter what I tried. My current implementation goes like this:

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app = express();
var jsonParser = bodyParser.json()

//Import static files
app.use(express.static('../public'))

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.post('/', jsonParser, (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body);
    res.send(200);
});

app.listen(port, () => console.log("Server started"));
```

No matter what I try from other posts, it still does not seem to return me any data.

[image]

Does anyone have an idea how to fix this problem?

Comment: Your request  body is url-form encoded, not JSON encoded, for what it's worth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why to you use 'jsonParser' in the app route? Try something like:

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.post('/post-test', (req, res) => {
    console.log('Got body:', req.body);
    res.sendStatus(200);
});
```